# Selenium "element click intercepted error "

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

url=https://www.hipodromx.com/galop.aspx?Page=1

I want to click on all the tabs in order and print the texts in the tables opened under them to the list, but when I run the code, I get the following error, I couldn't figure out why.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5OBl.png)

```
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPageControl1_cbGalopIstatistikMesafe_B-1Img']").click()
sleep(4)
TABLO=[]
for i in range(0,6):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPageControl1_cbGalopIstatistikMesafe_DDD_L_LBI{}T0']".format(i)).click()
    sleep(4)
    tablo = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@id,'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPageControl1_grdGalopIstatistik_DXDataRow')]//descendant::td")
    for i in tablo:
        TABLO.append(i.text)
tablo_duzenleme=[TABLO[x:x+10] for x in range(0, len(TABLO), 10)]
print(tablo_duzenleme)`
```

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <td class="dxeListBoxItem_Material" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPageControl1_cbGalopIstatistikMesafe_DDD_L_LBI0T0">...</td> is not clickable at point (358, 220). Other element would receive the click: <div class="dxh-content">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

when looping in for (0,6) range doesn't work for zero. It does not give an error, it operates on the currently defined tab("1000"). I couldn't figure out why
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dYkn.png)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver= webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Recep_PC\\Desktop\\driver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.hipodromx.com/galop.aspx?Page=1")
sleep(2)
TABLO=[]
for i in range(0,6):
    tab=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPageControl1_cbGalopIstatistikMesafe_B-1Img']")
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(tab).click().perform()
    sleep(2)
    sub_tab=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPageControl1_cbGalopIstatistikMesafe_DDD_L_LBI{}T0']".format(i))
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(sub_tab).click().perform()
    sleep(2)
    tablo = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@id,'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ASPxPageControl1_grdGalopIstatistik_DXDataRow')]//descendant::td")
    for i in tablo:
        TABLO.append(i.text)

tablo_duzenleme=[TABLO[x:x+10] for x in range(0, len(TABLO), 10)]
print(tablo_duzenleme)
```